# Invariant operators in the Heisenberg picture?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, qft-in-curved-spacetime

### Background + My attempt

I was recently thinking about the Heisenberg picture in Special Relativity:

$$ \frac{dO(t)}{dt}=\frac{dU^\dagger \hat OU}{dt} = U^\dagger\frac{[H,O]}{-i \hbar}U $$

However this is not an invariant quantity. So I thought I could define a new invariant operator:

$$ \frac{d U^\dagger \hat OU}{d t}. \frac{dt}{d\tau} = \gamma \frac{[H,O]}{-i \hbar} $$

where $\gamma(v(t))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}} $

### Questions

Is this correct? I couldn't find this on the internet ... Also how does one define an invariant operator in special relativity and for any arbitrary metric?

Comment: what is $v$ in $\gamma$?

Comment: $v$ is the velocity of the observer.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: I recommend to read 'Relativistic quantum mechanics' on Wikipedia. There are also 2 references for applying SR to the Heisenberg picture

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I'm sure why that would be a problem. Let there be 2 observers one moving with velocity $v$ away from the other. (This can be done by one observer continuously shooting a light beam at the other). Then I think it is a valid question to ask what would one measure the rate of change of an operator say position transform in different frames?

Comment: @AnantSaxena it appears to me that you aren't quite sure yourself of what you want to do. In the relativistic setting, you could either describe quantum relativistic particles (look up Dirac theory of the electron, for example), or you could do field theory (try reading about Quantum Field Theory), which is a more general approach.